# is there a way at compile time to insert the data of an initialized struct to an other of the same type?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct info {
    int     id;
    char*   name;
} info_t;

static  info_t info1[] =
{
    {
        .id   =  0,
        .name = "aaa",
    },
    {
        .id   =  1,
        .name = "bbb",
    },
};

static info_t info2[] =
{
    { 
        info1,
    },
    {
        .id   =  2,
        .name = "ccc",
    },
};
```

in my example I would like that at compile time `struct info2` would be sized with three elements where the first two have the same data of `info1`

Comment: No, but you could use macros.

Comment: Why would you need such redundancy anyway? Would be justified if both arrays only share the initial values and might then develop independently, but otherwise there might be better means.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this if you declare `info1` as `const` and are willing to use non-standard language features with a slightly different syntax.

The following works with GCC and Clang, but as it relies on non-standard compiler-specific handling of `const` expressions within definitions it may not work on other compilers.

```c
typedef struct info{
    int     id;
    char*   name;
} info_t;

// notice the added "const" here
static const info_t info1 [] =
{
    {
        .id   =  0,
        .name = "aaa",
    },
    {
        .id   =  1,
        .name     = "bbb",
    },
};

static info_t info2 [] =
{
    info1[0],
    info1[1],
    {
        .id   =  2,
        .name     = "ccc",
    },
};
```

If you want a generic method where you don't have to specify the elements (`[0]`, `[1]` and so on) then that is not possible.

Comment: This is relying on non-portable, compiler-specific features. Specifically, on implementation-defined constant expressions. There is no consensus that this is conforming C but gcc and clang implemented it anyway. Compile this with a gcc version from back in the days (version 7 or older) when gcc was strictly conforming in `-pedantic-errors` mode and not the complete bug fest of today. Then you'll get the expected compiler errors. Notably C has not changed at all here from C89 to C17. The only thing that has changed are sketchy compiler modifications.

Comment: Also since the OP is asking this question they likely already tried with a strictly conforming compiler, which didn't let them write code like this. So I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @Lundin the question is "is there a way at compile time to insert the data of an initialized struct to an other of the same type?" - so it definitely does answer it. You are right about the portability of the code though.

Comment: This isn't tagged gcc though so we should assume conforming C.

Answer (score 1):

The old school way is to put the initializer list in a macro:

```
#define INFO1_INITLIST          \
    {                           \
        .id   =  0,             \
        .name = "aaa",          \
    },                          \
    {                           \
        .id   =  1,             \
        .name     = "bbb",      \
    },


static info_t info1 [] =
{
    INFO1_INITLIST
};

static info_t info2 [] =
{
    INFO1_INITLIST

    {
        .id   =  2,
        .name     = "ccc",
    },
};
```

This can be further generalized and made even more maintainable with "X macros" (a common function-like macro design pattern), although obscure for those not used to the style:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct info{
    int     id;
    char*   name;
} info_t;

#define info_t_initializer(id_, name_) { .id = (id_), .name=(name_), },

#define INFO1_INITLIST(X) \
/*  id  name */           \
  X( 0, "aaa")            \
  X( 1, "bbb")            \

#define INFO2_INITLIST(X) \
/*  id  name */           \
  X( 2, "ccc")            \


static info_t info1 [] =
{
    INFO1_INITLIST(info_t_initializer)
};

static info_t info2 [] =
{
    INFO1_INITLIST(info_t_initializer)
    INFO2_INITLIST(info_t_initializer)
};

int main (void)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof info2 / sizeof *info2; i++)
  {
    printf("id: %d name: %s\n", info2[i].id, info2[i].name);
  }
}
```